# Simplify trigonometric expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Mathematica correctly simplifies the following expression:

```
Assuming[-Pi <= θ <= Pi, FullSimplify[TrigToExp[
                                    1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cot[θ/2]]^2] - Abs[Sin[θ/2]]]]]
(*0*)
```

But it will not simplify

```
Assuming[-Pi <= θ <= Pi, FullSimplify[1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cot[θ/2]]^2]]]
(*1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cot[θ/2]]^2]*)
```

to

```
Abs[Sin[θ/2]]
```

Even though it has less fractions, less square-roots and less sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you exclude the singular point:

```
Assuming[2 Pi > θ > 0,  FullSimplify[1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cot[θ/2]]^2]]]
(* Sin[θ/2] *)
```

Comment: But why is Mathematica able to deal with the singular point in my first `FullSimplify` expression?

Comment: @MrZ Because `TrueQ[ComplexInfinity == ComplexInfinity]` is false. Try `Reduce[1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cot[\[Theta]/2]]^2] == 
   Sin[\[Theta]/2], \[Theta], Reals] /. C[1] -> 0`